# angular directive referring to controller

Tags: angularjs

I thought I had the syntax correct so I don't understand where this error is coming from.

TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error occurs in the directive, line 13: var refresh = scope.reloadFunction().

Am I not pointing at getCampaignData correctly?

Directive:

```
1    angular.module('sysomos.ads').directive('sysReportResubmit', ['$api', '$alerts',
2       function ($api, $alerts) {
3           return {
4               restrict: 'A',
5               scope: {
6                   reloadFunction: '&'
7               },
8               link: function (scope, element) {
9                   element.on('click', function (e) {
10                      $api.put('', 'myAPICall').
11                          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
12                              scope.results = data;
13                              var refresh = scope.reloadFunction();
14                              refresh.then(function () {**
15                                  $(target).removeClass('panel-loading');
16                              }
17                          });
18                      }).
19                  }
20              }
21          });
22      };
23    }
```

Controller

```
1    angular.module('sysomos.ads').controller('AudienceDetailsController', AudienceDetailsController);
3    AudienceDetailsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$api', '$http','$state', '$q', '$filter', '$modal', 'AudienceListsService'];
3    function AudienceDetailsController($scope, $api, $http, $state, $q, $filter, $modal, AudienceListsService) {
4       $scope.**getCampaignData** = function(){
5           // reload page data
6       }
7    }
```

HTML Template

```
1    <section id="details" ng-controller="AudienceDetailsController">
2       <a
3           class="tabflowButton" reload-function="getCampaignData" sys-report-resubmit>
4               Resubmit
5       </a>
6    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem here is that the `&` refers to an expression.

Passing the function name in requires the braces:

```
<section id="details" ng-controller="AudienceDetailsController">
  <a class="tabflowButton" reload-function="getCampaignData()" sys-report-resubmit>Resubmit</a>
</section>
```

This video really helped be understand Isolate scope:
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope

Comment: Right, so I make that change, and then I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". Now it does not recognize that the reload function holds anything.

Comment: You are calling then() on the object the getCampaignData() function returns. Make sure it is returning an object and that it includes the necessary functionality.